# javascript set weight to characters in text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply text `"<b>H</b>ell<b>o</b>"` to the paragraph with id="predogled" using javascript, so the output will be **H**ell**o**.

I tried with this:

```
<script>
    function formattext(){
        document.getElementById('predogled').innerText="<b>H</b>ell<b>o</b>";
    }
</script>

<p id="predogled"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="formattext()">Format!</button>
```

But this code literally print `"<b>H</b>ell<b>o</b>"` and the characters are not bold as I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `innerText` does. If you want it to be interpreted as HTML, use `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use innerHTML

```js
<script>
    function formattext(){
        document.getElementById('predogled').innerHTML="<b>H</b>ell<b>o</b>";
    }
</script>
```

```html
<p id="predogled"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="formattext()">Format!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `innerText` you print a string.
With `innerHTML` you print the HTML content of the elements.
Try using `innerHTML` besides `innerText`:

```
function formattext(){
        document.getElementById('predogled').innerHTML="<b>H</b>ell<b>o</b>";
    }
```